# Read / Load JSON response from PHP Web API to WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, json, wpf, webapi

Below is my JSON response from PHP Web API. I need this "tradeType" to be loaded in WPF ComboBox after checking "success"is true/false, If false display Error message shown in "message"

```json
{
    "success":"true",
    "message":"Trade Type List",
    "tradeType":[
        {"id":1, "name":"Coaching Class"},
        {"id":2,"name":"Food Supply"},
        {"id":3,"name":"Marriage Bureau"}
    ]
}
```

I am new to WPF and Web API, what i have tried is

```cs
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();    
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://offline.localhost.in/");    
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));    
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/utilities/trade_types").Result;    
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)    
{    
    var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();    
    Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TradeType>>(jsonString);                   
    cmbTrade.ItemsSource = users;    
}    
else    
{    
    MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);    
}
```

Comment: What part of the above code is your question about? Does it compile? Are you getting an exception or what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class TradeType
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<TradeType> tradeType { get; set; }
}

private void GetData()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://offline.localhost.in/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/utilities/trade_types").Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
        myDeserializedClass.tradeType.Insert(0, new TradeType { id = 0, name = "-Select-" });
        cmbTrade.ItemsSource = myDeserializedClass.tradeType;
        cmbTrade.DisplayMemberPath = "name";
        cmbTrade.SelectedValuePath = "id";
        cmbTrade.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You are missing an `await` here so the call is fired but not awaited. Also have `Task` in var instead the `string`.

```
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

or use the non-async version.